# How are margins of error related to confidence Intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, survey, polling

Can somebody tell me the difference between margins of error and confidence intervals? On the Internet I see these two meanings getting used interchangeably.

Is it right to say,

"Confidence intervals are shown as 1.96 and displayed on the graphs as error margins"?

Comment: Useful discussions on this topic can be found by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=%2bmargin%20%2berror%20%2bconfidence).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Internet is full of garbage, as all of us know.  It helps to find authoritative sources and focus on them to help resolve such issues.  A [pamphlet](http://www.amstat.org/sections/srms/pamphlet.pdf) published by the [American Statistical Association](http://www.amstat.org/) (attributed to Fritz Scheuren and "thoroughly updated circa 1997") *defines* the margin of error as a 95% confidence interval (p. 64, at right).

In light of this, it is surprising that the [Wikipedia article on margin of error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error) uses a different definition, even though it references this pamphlet!  Wikipedia writes,

> The margin of error is usually defined as the "radius" (or half the width) of a confidence interval for a particular statistic from a survey. ... When a single, global margin of error is reported for a survey, it refers to the maximum margin of error for all reported percentages using the full sample from the survey.

In other words, to Wikipedia the MoE is *one-half* the *maximum* width of a set of confidence intervals (which might have coverages differing from 95%).

We have discussed this confusion (or, at least, lack of standardization) in comments elsewhere on this site.  Our conclusion was that **you need to be clear what *you* mean by "margin of error" whenever you use that term.**

Answer (score 7):

There is no universally followed convention on what a "margin of error" is but I think (as you have observed) it is most often used as meaning the [radius of a confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21139/correct-terminology-for-describing-relative-confidence-interval), either in the original scale of the estimate or as a percentage of an estimate.  Sometimes it is used as synonymous with the "standard error", so you need to be careful that others understand what you mean when you use it.

A "confidence interval" *does* have universal convention on its meaning.  It basically is the range of possible estimates generated by an estimating process that would, X% of the time (95% being the most commonly used) contain the true value of the parameter being estimated.  This concept of a "process" that would produce the true value X% of the time is a bit counter-intuitive and not to be mixed up with a ["credibility interval"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval) from Bayesian inference, which has a much more intuitive definition, but is not the same thing as the widely used confidence interval.

Your actual quote is a little messy and needs some minor fixing as described.  I would avoid this additional use of the word "margin" and favour "error bars".  So:

"Confidence intervals are estimated as 1.96 multiplied by the relevant standard errors and shown on the graphs as error bars."

(This puts aside the question whether this is a good way to calculate confidence intervals, which depends on your model etc and isn't relevant).

Final comment on terminology - I don't like "standard error", which just means "the standard deviation of the estimate"; or "sampling error" in general - I prefer to think in terms of randomness, and the variance of statistics, rather than "errors".  But I slipped into using the term "standard error" above because it is so widely used I guess.