# Contradiction in statistical significance between standard error bars and unpaired t test

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, standard-error

My data shows that there is NO overlap of the standard errors of the mean but my unpaired two tailed t-test shows that the difference in the means is not statistically significant? How can I interpret this data: is the difference in means significant or not?

Comment: Please show us the details: how were the standard errors computed, how was the t-test conducted, and how have you determined that the t-test result is not significant and at what level of significance?

Comment: I calculated the standard errors and t test on an online programme! I determined the t test result to be significant as the t statistic was greater than the critical value! The level of significance was P<0.05.

Comment: You need to find out exactly what each of these "standard errors" represents and you need to confirm that they (and the t-test) were correctly computed.  However, overlap (or non-overlap) of standard errors or confidence intervals is not usually a valid hypothesis test--so it is premature to assert there's any kind of "contradiction."  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31657 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18215, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If standard errors do not overlap then the difference in means must be at least 2 standard errors apart. The standard error of the difference between means is 1.44 x the standard error. Multiply that by 2 (approximately the t) the difference has to be about 3 standard errors apart.

Comment: This will be correct and useful if the standard errors are approximately the same and neither of the sample sizes is extremely small.