# How to calculate statistically relevant number of surveys when measuring NPS

Tags: statistical-significance, likert

NPS Explained:

The customer is asked, "How likely is it that you would recommend [your company] to a friend or colleague?" and customers respond on a 1-10 scale

I receive a large number of completed NPS surveys per month and are required to look at the NPS different business areas and interaction groupings within the company each of which have different average survey volumes. I am looking to calculate the number of surveys at which measuring the NPS becomes statistically relevant.

• Promoters (score 9-10) are loyal enthusiasts who will keep buying and refer others, fueling growth.
• Passives (score 7-8) are satisfied but unenthusiastic customers who are vulnerable to competitive offerings.
• Detractors (score 0-6) are unhappy customers who can damage your brand and impede growth through negative word-of-mouth.

The percentage of customers who are Promoters is then subtracted from the percentage who are Detractors.

Comment: It is unclear what "statistically relevant" might mean, but are you perhaps asking the same question as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18603?

Comment: It is also unclear what 'number of surveys' means. Do you mean number of observations?