# About Standard Error of the Mean

Tags: standard-error

Standard Error of the Mean

I do not clearly  understand about 'Standard Error of the Mean'? I tried understanding about it but I failed.

How do you calculate in order to retrieve 'Standard Error of the Mean' by using a concrete and simple example?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you after an explanation of what it is or an explanation of how to calculate it?

Comment: Make it both om them

Comment: Many concrete, simple examples of this calculation have appeared on this site: please [search for "standard error mean"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=standard+error+mean) and explore the 1000+ posts it produces. One very simple, fully worked example that I can recall appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18603.