# How to calculate p-value for NPS (Net Promoter Score) result?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, z-score

There's already [an excellent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18603/how-can-i-calculate-margin-of-error-in-a-nps-net-promoter-score-result) on calculating MoEs and confidence interval to compare NPS results from two samples.

However I would like to find a p-value (or at least a z-score) as a result of the comparison. Is it possible at all? My stats knowledge is rather limited.