# Is standard error a function of population standard deviation?

Tags: standard-error

I was watching [a lecture video on hypothesis test from Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/significance-tests-one-sample/more-significance-testing-videos/v/hypothesis-testing-and-p-values). At 4m 26s of the video, the lecturer defines standard error. Here he says that 'We don't know the standard deviation of the population, but the sample standard deviation is a good estimation, when the sample size is large enough'. To me it sounds odd. The standard error is defined as a sample standard deviation over square root of the sample size. There's no reason to talk about the population standard deviation. Am I wrong?

Comment: You quote a *formula* for a standard error, not a definition.  In an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18609/919, I introduce the idea of the standard error from basic principles, using no mathematics.  Perhaps that answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard deviation of the population mean, since it is a fixed constant and constants have no standard deviation (if you really want to define one, it would have to be 0, unless you go onto a Bayesian framework).

However, there is a population standard deviation: the standard deviation of the distribution from which we draw our sample.