# Margin of Error in a NPS result with promoters only

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, standard-error, multinomial-distribution, net-promoter-score

This is a follow-up to the response provided by @whuber on the question [How can I calculate margin of error in a NPS (Net Promoter Score) result?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18603/how-can-i-calculate-margin-of-error-in-a-nps-net-promoter-score-result)

@whuber pointed out that there are more sophisticated methods that use the same concept of variance of discrete variables to calculate margin of error where any one of the 3 types of customers (promoters, detractors or passives) is closer to 0.

Could someone please provide an example of these sophisticated approaches to the calculation of margin of error for NPS where the respondents are only promoters or only detractors?