# Calculating sample size for NPS (Net Promoter Score)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I am having trouble understanding how I can go about calculating the sample size required to run a t-test for a NPS score.

For those unfamiliar, NPS is a score that is essentially (# of promoters - # of detractors)/# of total surveys

My understanding is that this is not quite a straight forward proportions test because of the # of promoters - # of detractors aspect of it.

I have referenced this really good page here [How can I calculate margin of error in a NPS (Net Promoter Score) result?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18603/how-can-i-calculate-margin-of-error-in-a-nps-net-promoter-score-result)

But I'm unsure of how to calculate the sample size required for me to reach statistical significance for my test here.

Any guidance is much appreciated.